# Can blocking referer spam by black listing domains in google analytics have a positive effect on ranking due to reduced bounce rate ?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer, spam-prevention, bounce-rate, bounce

I have a site thats getting a lot of referral spam in google analytics both for referred traffic and organic traffic (where they place the their site name in the keyword field).

Because its all bot traffic it has always has a 100% bounce rate which in turn is skewing the actual bounce rate average.

Would blocking the referral spam by using the techniques listed here : http://www.cgcolors.com/blog/block-unwanted-referral-traffic-google-analytics-report/ - reduce my over the bounce average, and thus possible have a positive effect on the sites rankings (as bounce rate is a ranking factor)

Comment: As below, GA is simply a reporting tool and filtering the reports won't affect the raw numbers.  But if you can block the bots through other means and lower your bounce rate you WILL get a positive effect from it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you do in Google Analytics can effect search performance. It is an analytics program that reports what has already happened. Your filtering referrer spam in analytics only effects the reports you see. Nothing more.